# Updating source of WPF image from background thread takes forever

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm trying to update the source of an image control on the UI of my WPF app.

The code runs in nano seconds when called from the UI thread. When I set the source from a background thread, it takes some 60 - 80 seconds to complete.

What is causing the delay? How do I speed it up?

This is how am changing the image source from the background thread:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    catImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fullCatURLPath, UriKind.Absolute));
}));
```

Comment: Yes. In other words: Profile your application with visual studio and locate the hot spots.

Comment: My understanding is that you need to [freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710560/using-bitmapimage-created-on-threadpool-thread) a bitmap created on a background thread before using it on another thread.  So, maybe give that a try?

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke does not run anything in a background thread. It just executes the Action synchronously on the Dispatcher thread, i.e. the UI thread. See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16041810/1136211) for how to load an image in a separate thread.